SDDM freeze when switching users on Debian fresh install
I have an issue with sessions switching in Debian/KDE plasma (problem with SDDM I think?).
I've been using Ubuntu for years but I don't know much about the details of how Linux works.
I installed Debian with KDE a week ago on my brand new Thinkpad and I am trying to keep everything clean (= understanding what I'm doing before I try anything). I did not tweak anything about my Debian or KDE apart from things in system settings. The wildest thing I did since install was creating a second user and adding it to the sudoers.
The problem : Every time I have 2 sessions active, if I logout from one of them, the system freezes just after logout. It can also happen when I simply switch users (but not every the time). The system freezes on the user login screen that hasn't been updated since last login (the time displayed is stuck to time of last login). The mousepad still works normally and the keyboard lights are still on. (Also, an odd detail : the battery icon always indicates that the laptop is charging, while it's not.)
I didn't find any solution online, but I found someone with the same issue : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1358950/kubuntu-login-screen-is-frozen-when-switching-users (tried debugging with the advice, didn't help).
The logs :
$ sudo journalctl --system
May 11 00:01:42 BER33000 sddm-helper[9975]: [PAM] Ended.
May 11 00:01:42 BER33000 sddm[901]: Auth: sddm-helper exited successfully
May 11 00:01:42 BER33000 sddm[901]: Socket server stopping...
May 11 00:01:42 BER33000 sddm[901]: Socket server stopped.
May 11 00:01:42 BER33000 sddm[901]: Display server stopping...
May 11 00:01:42 BER33000 systemd[1]: session-13.scope: Deactivated successfully.
May 11 00:01:42 BER33000 systemd-logind[827]: Session 13 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
May 11 00:01:42 BER33000 systemd-logind[827]: Removed session 13.
May 11 00:01:42 BER33000 sddm[901]: Display server stopped.
May 11 00:01:42 BER33000 sddm[901]: Running display stop script  "/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xstop"
May 11 00:01:42 BER33000 sddm[901]: Removing display ":2" ...
May 11 00:01:42 BER33000 sddm[901]: Jumping to VT 7
May 11 00:01:42 BER33000 sddm[901]: VT mode didn't need to be fixed
May 11 00:01:52 BER33000 systemd[1]: Stopping user@1000.service - User Manager for UID 1000...
May 11 00:01:52 BER33000 systemd[1]: user@1000.service: Deactivated successfully.
May 11 00:01:52 BER33000 systemd[1]: Stopped user@1000.service - User Manager for UID 1000.
May 11 00:01:52 BER33000 systemd[1]: user@1000.service: Consumed 31min 59.115s CPU time.
May 11 00:01:52 BER33000 systemd[1]: Stopping user-runtime-dir@1000.service - User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000...
May 11 00:01:52 BER33000 systemd[1]: run-user-1000.mount: Deactivated successfully.
May 11 00:01:52 BER33000 systemd[1]: user-runtime-dir@1000.service: Deactivated successfully.
May 11 00:01:52 BER33000 systemd[1]: Stopped user-runtime-dir@1000.service - User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000.
May 11 00:01:52 BER33000 systemd[1]: Removed slice user-1000.slice - User Slice of UID 1000.
May 11 00:01:52 BER33000 systemd[1]: user-1000.slice: Consumed 31min 59.392s CPU time.
May 11 00:02:18 BER33000 systemd-logind[827]: Power key pressed short.

My detailed system info :

Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 12
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.103.0
Qt Version: 5.15.8
Kernel Version: 6.1.0-21-amd64 (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: Wayland
Processors: 16 × AMD Ryzen 7 PRO 6850U with Radeon Graphics
Memory: 11.4 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: AMD Radeon Graphics
Manufacturer: LENOVO
System Version: ThinkPad P14s Gen 3

